# FFMPEG Installation on cPanel

Tags: ffmpeg, cpanel

I have installed the cumulus video script on cPanel, but now am unable to upload videos. 
This is the error I am receiving:

> The following errors were found. Please correct them and try again.
>
> - Invalid path to FFMPEG

I have uploaded "ffmpeginstaller.7.4.tar.gz" to the public root of my domain, and have unzipped the files. However it still gives the error of invalid path to FFMPEG.

I have tried putting the directory of "adtube.run-time.co.za/ffmpeginstaller.7.4.tar.gz" as the FFMPEG path in the cumulus script admin panel settings, but still no luck.

This is [my website](http://www.adtube.run-time.co.za).

Please could someone point me in the right direction of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FFMPEG feature should be installed in your hosting server. If you want to install it into the server you need a root access. If you are in a dedicated/VPS server you can install it using the root. In the case of shared hosting you need to contact your hosting provider for installing [FFMPEG](http://hioxindia.com/ffmpeg-hosting.php).

Answer (score 1):

You have to VPS or dedicated server with root access to install FFMPEG, here is one direction to install ffmpeg http://help.digipower.vn/questions/139/How+to+Install+ffmpeg

Comment: thank you.  where do I insert those lines of code? such as"1 # cd /usr/local/src"  ? I have access to WHM of the cPanel as well, would I use that?

Comment: you have to access server by using SSH connect , here is one turorial with hostname is your server's IP address or your hosted domain name on server http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/general-server-setup/how-to-login-ssh

Comment: That guide is now old, the hosted files no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

Install ffmpeg FOR Cpanel & Centos servers. (At this time)

http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/ffmpeg-318681.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFMPEG static build from here
https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/